# How to integrate service now with Azure YAML pipeline to create change ticket

Tags: azure-devops, servicenow, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have integrated service now with azure release pipeline but the same need to be integrate with Azure YAML pipeline. Does service now supports YAML pipeline integration to create change ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly need some more clarification but on the surface can you get ServiceNow to call the Azure Pipeline API - [Azure Pipeline API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

I presume you are already calling the  [Azure Release API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)